# Multiple Tiles in Periodic Update

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

Can I return multiple tiles as XML? How does 'Weather', 'Finance' or 'News' applications show multiple results in tile? I tried to create an XML like this but it didn't work:

```
<tile>
    <visual lang="en-US">
        <binding template="TileWideSmallImageAndText04">
            <image id="1" src="URLOFIMG" alt="alt text"/>
            <text id="1">Some Text</text>
            <text id="2">Text Field 2</text>
        </binding>
        <binding template="TileWideSmallImageAndText04">
            <image id="1" src="URL2" alt="alt text"/>
            <text id="1">SOME TEXT</text>
            <text id="2">Text Field 2</text>
        </binding>
        <binding template="TileWideSmallImageAndText04">
            <image id="1" src="URL" alt="alt text"/>
            <text id="1">TEXT</text>
            <text id="2">Text Field 2</text>
        </binding>
    </visual>
</tile>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Placing more than one wide tile binding (or more than one square tile binding) into a single XML payload is not allowed.  Put another way, a tile notification XML payload can contain at most one wide tile binding and at most one square tile binding.

That said, it is possible to provide multiple tile notifications via periodic updates, or any other delivery mechanism (local, push, or scheduled).

By default, a tile will only display the most recent tile notification.  By [enabling the tile notification queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.notifications.tileupdater.enablenotificationqueue), up to five tile notifications can be stored for any given tile at a time.

Periodic updates can then be configured to download on each interval from one web URL using [TileUpdater.StartPeriodicUpdate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.notifications.tileupdater.startperiodicupdate.aspx), or from up to five web URLs using [TileUpdater.StartPeriodicUpdateBatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.notifications.tileupdater.startperiodicupdatebatch).  By providing URLs that return distinct tile notification XML payloads, multiple notifications will be shown on a tile.

More details on periodic updates here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh761476

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried looking at the [sample app](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Secondary-Tiles-Sample-edf2a178)?

```
    private void SendTileNotificationWithStringManipulation_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
    { 
        Button button = sender as Button; 
        if (button != null) 
        { 
            string tileXmlString = "<tile>" 
                                 + "<visual>" 
                                 + "<binding template='TileWideText04'>" 
                                 + "<text id='1'>Send to a secondary tile from strings</text>" 
                                 + "</binding>" 
                                 + "<binding template='TileSquareText04'>" 
                                 + "<text id='1'>Send to a secondary tile from strings</text>" 
                                 + "</binding>" 
                                 + "</visual>" 
                                 + "</tile>"; 

            Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument tileDOM = new Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument(); 
            tileDOM.LoadXml(tileXmlString); 
            TileNotification tile = new TileNotification(tileDOM); 

            // Send the notification to the secondary tile by creating a secondary tile updater 
            TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForSecondaryTile(MainPage.dynamicTileId).Update(tile); 

            rootPage.NotifyUser("Tile notification sent to " + MainPage.dynamicTileId, NotifyType.StatusMessage); 
        } 
    }
```

Example of how to pin secondary tiles found in `PinLiveTile_Click()`

Edit:
To do periodic updates see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh761461.aspx).

Comment: no I'm not trying to do this. What I need is to send multiple tiles with 'the same' template. So they all can appear in the same place.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the same place"

Comment: As Nathan pointed it out in his answer you can not send multiple notifications in single update.

Answer (score 0):

As Nathan pointed out you can only have one square and one wide tile but take a look at the range of wide tile (in particular TileWidePeekImageCollection06)
The list of available tile can be found here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh761491.aspx#TileWideImageAndText01

If this still doesn't solve your requirement then the only other way to do it is to use secondary tiles.

Comment: the link has been recently updated to include windows phone 8.1 updates. some nice new tiles have been added and some tile renamed.
Example source code http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/App-tiles-and-badges-sample-5fc49148/view/SourceCode